# Change MySQL Timezone Windows

Tags: java, mysql, windows, rest

I try change timezone in *my.ini* but it doesn't work.

Use different variants:

```
default-time-zone = "Europe/Moscow"
default_time_zone = "Europe/Moscow"
default-time-zone = "+03:00"
and so on
```

But when I change it by `SET GLOBAL time_zone = '+3:00';` all work fine.

I want change timezone, because my REST API doesn't work and throw exeption:

com.mysql.cj.core.exceptions.InvalidConnectionAttributeException: The server time zone value 'Russia TZ 2 Standard Time' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone.

UPD:

I found strange behavior for my installation:

When I was changed time_zone via Workbench it create new folder in ProgramData.

Now it contain two folders **MySQL Server 5.5** and **MySQL Server 5.7**. Maybe problem with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem resolved by adding my.ini file into installation folder and [initialise](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/data-directory-initialization.html) it

ALso work this:

```
SET GLOBAL time_zone = '+3:00';
```

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 10 I have found that I can do that by editing "C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Data\mysqld-auto.cnf".

```
"mysql_server" : { "time_zone" : { "Value" : "SYSTEM" ...
```

Don't forget to restart MYSQL80 service after editing this file.

Answer (score 0):

Mysql prompt:

SELECT @@global.time_zone = "-4:00"

after:

restart

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score -2):

```
Login to your server via SSH as the root user.
You can view MySQL's current time zone settings using the following command from the console:

mysql -e "SELECT @@global.time_zone;"
By default you should get back something similar to:

+--------------------+
| @@global.time_zone |
+--------------------+
| SYSTEM             |
+--------------------+
This is because by default your MySQL time zone will be set to the server's default SYSTEM time. If you're interested in changing the entire server's time zone this can be accomplished by setting the time zone in WHM.

You can see the server's SYSTEM time stamp using the following command:

date
Which will give back:

Mon Nov 26 12:50:07 EST 2012

You can see the current time stamp reported by the MySQL server using the following command:

mysql -e "SELECT NOW();"
This should give back the current time stamp:

+---------------------+
| NOW()               |
+---------------------+
| 2012-11-26 12:50:15 |
+---------------------+
Now you can edit your MySQL configuration file with your favorite text editor:

vi /etc/my.cnf
Then add the following line to change from EST (GMT -5:00) to CST (GMT -6:00):

default-time-zone = '-06:00'
Now save the /etc/my.cnf file with your new default.

To make the change active you'll want to restart the MySQL service with the following command:

service mysql restart

Now if you try to see the global time zone setting again with the command:

mysql -e "SELECT @@global.time_zone;"
You should now get back your new default:

+--------------------+
| @@global.time_zone |
+--------------------+
| -06:00             |
+--------------------+
You should also see now that the NOW() function has updated as well:

mysql -e "SELECT NOW();"
This should give back the current time stamp:

+---------------------+
| NOW()               |
+---------------------+
| 2012-11-26 11:50:15 |
+---------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, but it good for Linux server. I use Windows 7.